# Is there an efficient way to get a random value from struct?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got a struct, which has the same type attributes:

```
public struct SomeTypes
{
    public string type1;
    public string type2;
    public string type3;
    public string type4;
}
```

They all have been assigned an unique value. All I need to do is take one random value from this struct.

For example:

```
SomeTypes myTypes;

private string GetRandomType(){
    //Instead of:
    return myTypes.type1; //Or type2 etc.
    //This is what I want:
    return myTypes.takeOneRandom();
}
```

This might be a complicated solution for this type of problem, but if it's possible, I'd like to know how to do this with a struct.

Comment: With struct its complicated. But you can use list of strings or dynamic type. Why struct?

Comment: Because I have a fixed number of "types", more precisely, assigned Sprites in editor. The reason I did it with struct, because it's more readable in editor than array or list, which appears as "Element 0", "Element 1" and, of course, easier to access in code. But I'm afraid, I have over-complicated this already

Comment: So use a Dictionary type, key is name and value is your type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a fixed number of "types", more precisely, **assigned Sprites in editor**.

I would simply initialize an array with the given fields and use that to get a random entry using [`Random.Range`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html)

```
[Serializable]
public struct YourStruct
{
    public Sprite sprite1;
    public Sprite sprite2;
    public Sprite sprite3;
    public Sprite sprite4;

    private Sprite[] sprites;

    public Sprite RandomSprite
    {
        get
        {
            // lazy initialization of array
            if (sprites == null) sprites = new[] { sprite1, sprite2, sprite3, sprite4 };

            // pick random
            return sprites[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, sprites.Length)];
        }
    }
}
```

and later use it like

```
public YourStruct yourStruct;

...

Sprite randomSprite = yourStruct.RandomSprite;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick with relflection:

```
void Main()
{
     SomeTypes s = new SomeTypes();
    s.type1 = "asdsad";
    s.type2 = "damn";
    s.type3 = "damn1";
    s.type4 = "damn2";

    var t = typeof(SomeTypes).GetFields(); // get all fields

    Random r = new Random();
    int rInt = r.Next(0, t.Length); // create a random number in range of property count

    var res = s.GetType().GetField(t[rInt].Name); // get random property name

    var randomValue = res.GetValue(s);//get that property value
}

public struct SomeTypes
{
    public string type1;
    public string type2;
    public string type3;
    public string type4;
}
```

This has been tested using LinqPad

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to reformat your code and have an array instead of different fields:

```
public struct SomeTypes
{
    private Random random;
    public string[] types;

    public SomeTypes(IList<string> types)
    {
        this.types = (string[]) types;
        random = new Random();
    }

    public string takeOneRandom()
    {
        int index = random.Next(types.Length);
        return types[index];
    }
}
```

```
SomeTypes myTypes = new SomeTypes(new string[]{"t0", "t1", "t2", "t3"});

Console.WriteLine(myTypes.takeOneRandom());
```

If you want to keep your fields, there are a couple of things you can do. You can provide an indexer with a switch, have a dictionary, or, as shown in other answer(s) you can use reflection.

Here is a solution with an indexer and a switch:

```
public struct SomeTypes
{
    private Random random;

    public string type1;
    public string type2;
    public string type3;
    public string type4;

    public SomeTypes(string t1, string t2, string t3, string t4)
    {
        type1 = t1;
        type2 = t2;
        type3 = t3;
        type4 = t4;
        random = new Random();
    }

    public string this[int idx]
    {
        get
        {
            switch (idx)
            {
                case 0 : return type1;
                case 1: return type2;
                case 2: return type3;
                case 3: return type4;
                default: throw new ArgumentException();
            }
        }
    }

    public string takeOneRandom()
    {
        int index = random.Next(4);
        return this[index];
    }
}
```

```
        SomeTypes myTypes = new SomeTypes("t0", "t1", "t2", "t3");

        Console.WriteLine(myTypes.takeOneRandom());
```

Comment: thank you for long, yet very clear answer. But I've got shorter, my case more fitting solution, which is very similar to your bottom one.

Answer (score 0):

I think the fact that it is a struct is not a problem for you, given that you only want to read one of the fields (that btw. should rather be properties). You can use reflection. Your struct instance will be automatically boxed, but that is not a problem as long as you just read.

Here is the code:

```
    struct SomeStruct
    {
        private static PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(SomeStruct).GetProperties();
        private static Random random = new Random();

        public string type1 { get; set; }
        public string type2 { get; set; }
        public string type3 { get; set; }
        public string type4 { get; set; }

        public string TakeOneRandom()
        {
            int index = random.Next(properties.Length);
            return properties[index].GetValue(this)?.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: this works as well, thank you. But in my case, getters and setters makes this struct useless, because I can't assign values in editor anymore.

Comment: @Marius: You can do the same with fields.